# Error in update.jags(model, n.iter, ...) : Error in node sd[1] Invalid parent values

Tags: gaussian, rjags

I am having error in node sd[1], it says invalid parent values in the compiler. I am working with a gaussian model for "Galaxies" data from "MASS"p package of R.

```
library(rjags)
library(MASS)
library(mcsm)

data("galaxies")
summary(galaxies)

y = galaxies
ngroups = 2
jags_data = list(y=y, n=length(y), ngroups=ngroups)

gaussmodel = "
model {
  for (i in 1:n) {
     y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[z[i]], tau[z[i]]) 
     z[i] ~ dcat(group_probs)
}
group_probs ~ ddirich(d)       
  for (j in 1:ngroups) {
  mu_raw[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1E-6)
  tau[j] ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
  sd[j] = pow(tau[j], -0.5) 
  d[j] = 2
}
mu = sort(mu_raw)
}
"

model = jags.model(textConnection(gaussmodel), data=jags_data,
                   n.chains=4)
update(model,n.iter=1E4)
samples = coda.samples(model=model, variable.names=c("mu", "sd", "group_probs"), n.iter=1E4, thin=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about rjags and bayesian analysis in detail but I think your problem is in the sd line of the code where sd=pow(tau[j],-0.5)

I believe the -0.5 is the problem. I am not sure if you intended for the value to be negative but it seemed that the value caused some problems to suffix in your dirichlet model.

Taking away the negative value seemed to do the trick.